# C# Switch on enum with multiple keys for same value

Tags: c#, .net, enums, switch-statement

I already searched on how to do a switch on the value instead of the enumeration key in C# but with no result, all the posts I've found says that we don't need to use the value, we can just use the key.

But in my case, I want to use the value because I made an enumeration with multiple keys sharing the same value, here's the code :

```
public enum PlayerPosition {
    North = 0,
    Top = 0, 
    South = 1,
    Bottom = 1,
    East = 2,
    Right = 2,
    West = 3,
    Left = 3
}


switch (obj.PlayerPosition)
{
    case PlayerPosition.North:
        // some code
        break;
    case PlayerPosition.South:
        // some code
        break;
    case PlayerPosition.East:
        // some code
        break;
    case PlayerPosition.West:
        // some code
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

I think this is working but I don't find it really readable...

What I would like to achieve is something like this :

```
switch (obj.PlayerPosition)
{
    case PlayerPosition.Top:
    case PlayerPosition.North:
        // some code
        break;
    case PlayerPosition.Bottom:
    case PlayerPosition.South:
        // some code
        break;
    case PlayerPosition.Right:
    case PlayerPosition.East:
        // some code
        break;
    case PlayerPosition.Left:
    case PlayerPosition.West:
        // some code
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

The example above doesn't work because it is a duplicated case label.
How could I achieve that ?

**EDIT** : In this enumeration North/Top, South/Bottom are exactly the same, they just represent the position of the player around a table with 4 chairs. But we have old configuration files who use North/South/East/West and new configuration files who are using Top/Bottom/Right/Left.

Comment: Those aliassed enums are .... evil.

Comment: But in your switch, just pick either North/South _or_ Top/Bottom. You don't need both and can't use both at the same time.

Comment: I need them for retro compatibility in our configurations files, I'll mark them as deprecated and we'll stop using them, so I'll be able to remove them later but for now we need this, it's a real pain in the *** yeah.

Comment: Either you have distinct enum values, then you can use the second version. Or you use the same values for some of the enum members, then you simply use the first version (and use the "primary" enum member). Where's the problem?

Comment: @AntoineThiry Can't you just map them to a *new* enum that uses the same int values? Having both old and new in the same enum might cause additional problems.

Comment: If you really need to see both cases, comment the second one.

Comment: Just use the new Enum Members. It should work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sf54Sq

Comment: You can do `case PlayerPosition.Top | PlayerPosition.North:`, but I'd personally follow other solutions (like commenting the second one).

Comment: I didn't realized before posting that I could just use the new values and let the others die.

Comment: @JayBuckman I don't really need to see them, the North, South, ... values will be abandoned in a later update, but for now we still have xml configuration files with those values

Comment: Edited the post with some more information about the enumeration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this in a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vlWqMX): Just using the new members will work:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    North  = 0, //old
    Top    = 0, //new
    South  = 1, //old
    Bottom = 1  //new
}

public static void Main()
{
    // Parse "old" from XML config (simulated)
    MyEnum test = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum),"North");
    //          = MyEnum.North

    switch(test)
    {
        case MyEnum.Top:
            Console.WriteLine("NORTH");
            break;
        case MyEnum.Bottom:
            Console.WriteLine("SOUTH");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Unsupported!");
            break;

    }
}
```

Will output "NORTH".

**Edit**

Just a word about the actual *problem* you are facing: Downward compatibility.
What I'd do is on startup check if the configs are compatible with your current program version. If not: go through "upgrade" functions that (save a backup of the old configs and then) transform configs to the current version and save them back to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the point about not using multiple enum labels with the same value.  Generally speaking, I would agree.  However, there are circumstances where you could argue that it does make some sense.  The following enum from the .NET System.Drawing libraries is an example:

```
  public enum RotateFlipType
  {
    Rotate180FlipXY = 0,
    RotateNoneFlipNone = 0,
    Rotate270FlipXY = 1,
    Rotate90FlipNone = 1,
    Rotate180FlipNone = 2,
    RotateNoneFlipXY = 2,
    Rotate270FlipNone = 3,
    Rotate90FlipXY = 3,
    Rotate180FlipY = 4,
    RotateNoneFlipX = 4,
    Rotate270FlipY = 5,
    Rotate90FlipX = 5,
    Rotate180FlipX = 6,
    RotateNoneFlipY = 6,
    Rotate270FlipX = 7,
    Rotate90FlipY = 7,
  }
```

This enum is used to represent the type of rotation or "flip" to perform on an image.  Note that some values are the same because, e.g., rotating 180 degrees is equivalent to flipping the X and Y axis.

Even in this example, there are probably other ways to represent the enum without duplicating values, but this method may be the most user-friendly.

I don't see anything inherently wrong with duplicating values, and indeed it is supported.  However, you aren't able to use these duplicate enum values in structures such as switch statements.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the parser for the configuration files to solve this before it even becomes a problem.

Your program should only ever be ONE version at a time. The way it is now, you have 2 versions of configuration files, and you're trying to maintain 2 versions of the code at the same time.

The normal way to handle older versions of configuration files is to convert the data to the new format when they are read, or to detect them when they are first opened and convert them on disk to the new version (optionally notifying the user).

Comment: Nitpick-mode on: That's a solution to the _problem_ but not to the _question_ ... (I agree , though)

Comment: Fildor is right, but this is certainly what I'll end up doing. Modifying the config file when read is certainly to way to keep only one version in the code.

Comment: @Fildor: Yep. That's the way the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is usually answered.

Comment: @MarkBenningflied I didn't know what was the XY problem, thanks !

Comment: @MarkBenningfield While I agree that this is a XY _and_ with your approach, I've seen answers being downvoted because "not answering the _question_" ... ( I personally wouldn't dv in that case, just saying)

Comment: @Fildor: That's true, but I've also known users to DV a post just because they had a toothache at the time, so it doesn't really do any good to worry about that. Now, if ten of them DV the thing, there might just be a problem with it.

Comment: _"but I've also known users to DV a post just because they had a toothache at the time"_ ... :D absolutely ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand the reason behind having two different labels for the same enum value without having two separate enums. Firslty to answer your question you could cast the enum value to an int and then do a comparison on the int...

```
int value =  (int)obj.PlayerPosition
```

But I would probably look at removing the duplicate values and having two enums

```
public enum PlayerPosition {
    Top = 0, 
    Bottom = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Left = 3
}

public enum CompassPosition {
    North = 0, 
    South= 1,
    East= 2,
    West = 3
}
```

If you wanted to convert between the two you could just cast, e.g.

```
PlayerPosition pos = PlayerPosition.Left;
CompassPosition compass = (CompassPosition)pos;
Console.WriteLine(compass.ToString());
```

Comment: Just using the new enum Members will also work. I.e.: for example parsed from XML: `value = PlayerPosition.North` will enter the case `PlayerPosition.Top`. I tested this in a fiddle (see my comment to the question)

Comment: @Hoots I can't do that with two separate enums, the thing here is that the enum will be parsed from an XML file, and deserialized into an object who holds the PlayerPosition.

Comment: OK, I would probably still have two enums... Use the PlayerPosition for everything except for when reading from the Xml file where a conversion to the PlayerPosition would happen.

Comment: What about Serialization? If internally it's 0, is it north or top 0?

Comment: I think this solution will be the hardest to realize, I don't really want to bother with conversion since the deserialization to my object handle this for me.
That's a good point, I should test to see which key it will takes.

Comment: No Problem. If you decide to convert on inbound read you would just need to implement IXmlSerializable interface... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why bother with all of this? Use only the new enum members in cases. In the next version of your program deprecate the old ones. Then write an upgrade tool, that goes through the configs and changes the old ones to the new ones on startup (you may include a compat-version to your configs, so you need to check only that in case configs are up-to-date) and you're done. In the version after that you should be able to remove the old ones from your code.

Comment: I've just had a thought, just store as a string and convert as needed. See my final Player class example above. Actually, I removed it as that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with an enum. The purpose of an enum is that each item will have a different value and can be distinguished from the others. Why would you have Top and North being the same thing when instead you can always use North and avoid the confusion of having Top in addition? I would personally just have North, South, East and West and remove the others.

However, as far as I am aware, this should work:

```
public enum PlayerPosition {
    North,
    Top, 
    South,
    Bottom,
    East,
    Right,
    West,
    Left
}

switch (obj.PlayerPosition)
{
    case PlayerPosition.Top:
    case PlayerPosition.North:
        // some code
        break;
    case PlayerPosition.Bottom:
    case PlayerPosition.South:
        // some code
        break;
    case PlayerPosition.Right:
    case PlayerPosition.East:
        // some code
        break;
    case PlayerPosition.Left:
    case PlayerPosition.West:
        // some code
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Comment: (Did not DV) OP explains why he needs that in the question.